# Searching for *.graphml files with the find utility

Tags: bash, find, regex

I am trying to find all my GRAPHML files under the current directory in bash. So I ran the following command:

```
find . -name *.graphml
```

And I get the error message:

```
find: paths must precede expression
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [path...] [expression]
```

What is wrong with the command above? The strange thing is that it works fine for other regexps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always enclose the pattern in quotes (e.g. `*.graphml` in your case). Otherwise it will be expanded by the shell before the find command. This means that `find` does not get a literal `*graphml` passed, but rather what the shell expands `*.graphml` to.

Therefore:

```
find . -name "*.graphml*"
```

See:

- [`man find`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find) which says: "Don't    forget to  enclose the pattern in quotes in order to protect it from expansion by the shell."
- A little more about [Quoting](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/varsubn.html) from the Advanced Bash Scripting Guide.